# Refresh div when function timer reaches 00:00

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make it so that when the stime function reaches 00:00, the div id "refresh" will refresh the content inside..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currenttime = '<? print date("F d, Y H:i:s", time())?>'
var montharray=new 
var serverdate=new Date(currenttime)

function stime(){
var fiveMinutes = 5 * 60 * 1000;
var untilNext = fiveMinutes - (serverdate % fiveMinutes);
var timer=(untilNext / 1000)
var minutes= "0" + Math.floor(untilNext / 1000 / 60)
var seconds= "0" + (timer - minutes * 60)
document.getElementById("stime").innerHTML=minutes.substr(-2)+":"+seconds.substr    (-2)
}

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("stime()", 1000)
}
</script>

<?php
echo '<div id="refresh">Health: <span style="float:right" id="stime"></span></div><br />';
?>
```

### My Question

Is it possible with that function, to make another function that would refresh the div when the stime function reaches 00:00 ?

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: It's not necessarily a problem.. It's more so that I'm wondering if it's possible with that function.. to make another function that would refresh the div when the stime function reaches 00:00 ---- I'm a beginner in programming so I'm not even sure if it's possible lol.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/). You can reload some part of your page without reloading your whole page.

Comment: you got the username jQuery? surprised that was available, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currenttime = '<? print date("F d, Y H:i:s", time())?>';
var montharray=new Array();
var serverdate=new Date(currenttime);
function doRefresh(){
    //code to refresh or ajax.
}
function stime(){
    var fiveMinutes = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    var untilNext = fiveMinutes - (serverdate % fiveMinutes);
    var timer=(untilNext / 1000);
    var minutes= "0" + Math.floor(untilNext / 1000 / 60);
    var seconds= "0" + (timer - minutes * 60);
    var timeString = minutes.substr(-2)+":"+seconds.substr(-2);    
    document.getElementById("stime").innerHTML=timeString;
    if(timeString==="00:00")
    {
         doRefresh();
    }
}

window.onload=function(){
    setInterval("stime()", 1000);
}
</script>

<?php
echo '<div id="refresh">Health: <span style="float:right" id="stime"></span></div><br />';
?>
```

try to end statements with ";".
it would be good to use indent.(Increase readablity). Please don't leave variables hanging.
         `var montharray=new`

Answer (score 0):

Make your setInterval like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    setInterval(stime, 1000)
}
```